# sqlsrv_fetch with sqlsrv_execute in MS SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to extract data from procedure stored on a remote MSSQL server.
[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php) says in `sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)`, `$stmt` refers to the resource returned by the `sqlsrv_query()` or `sqlsrv_execute()`.

Here is my code snippet ->

```
$sql = "exec USP_ABC_ABC_REPORT 'Apple','06/01/2014','10/29/2014','H','A'";

        $segment ='apple';
        $start_date='06/01/2014';
        $end_date ='10/29/2014';
        $something2 ='H';
        $something3 ='A';       

        $abc = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array( &$segment, &$start_date, &$end_date, &$something2, &$something3));


        if( $abcd = sqlsrv_execute( $abc)){
                 if(sqlsrv_fetch($abcd)){
                    $id = sqlsrv_get_field( $abcd, 0);
                    echo $id;
            }   else{
                    echo "fetch failed";
                }
        }
```

This snippet shows an error:

> sqlsrv_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.

sqlsrv_fetch() works fine if I use sqlsrv_query() instead of sqlsrv_execute/prepare. The possible reason is that sqlsrv_query() returns mixed output instead of boolean.

Could anyone help with using sqlsrv_fetch with execute.

Answer (score 0):

[`sqlsrv_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php) returns a boolean indicating success or failure.

If the call to `sqlsrv_prepare` is successful, it returns a statement resource. So you can just pass `$abc` as a parameter of `sqlsrv_fetch` and `sqlsrv_get_field`:

```
if (sqlsrv_fetch($abc)){
    $id = sqlsrv_get_field($abc, 0);
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Yes my prepare statement is working fine. So I have deleted my execute statement and used sqlsrv_fetch($abc) , as you have mentioned. This displays "fetch failed" (the else statement in above code). Is this due to some error in the remote server? Also, why doesn't the official PHP sqlsrv_fetch() post mentions that we can use prepare resource as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Your insights about the cause are correct. Check the documentation for [sqlsrv_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php) and each of the functions.

**sqlsrv_execute** returns either **true** or **false**, (*boolean*). And this is not what fetch is expecting as input.

Once you undestand the need of matching types of expected parameters on each function you will be able to get along easier with any sort of code.

> while into a develpment environment, try to `var_dump($abcd);` just after assigning to see its value.

Comment: var_dump dumps the information about the variable. I know about that. But since execute always returns boolean, how can I change the above code snippet. In case I am not following you correctly, kindly explain using code snippet.

Comment: What I mean is that sqlsrv_fetch() is expecting a resource as parameter, not a boolean. Thus, will not work this way. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php , the parameter is abc, not abcd. As good practice avoid using confusing var names.

Comment: I have replaced sqlsrv_fetch($abcd) with sqlsrv_fetch($abc). This displays "fetch failed" (the else statement in above code). Is this due to some error in the remote server? My prepare statement is working fine. Also, why doesn't the official PHP sqlsrv_fetch() post mentions that we can use prepare resource as a parameter?

Comment: The fetch can fail because of the statement. You are executing an stored procedure. Try changing it to a simple select and make sure it works, then you can think about an issue with the stored procedure or the query built. Note that you jave hardcoded the sql parameters.